# Reading byte and mask it in java

Tags: java, sockets, byte, mask

I should get ID from socket but this code is not giving the correct one. Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code? (see below for more information)

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSRecords; i++) {
    socketReader.read(cbuf, 0, 4);
    String Param_Codes_In_HEX =
        Integer.toHexString(0x000000ff & cbuf[2]) +
        Integer.toHexString(0x000000ff & cbuf[1]) +
        Integer.toHexString(0x000000ff & cbuf[0]);
    System.out.println("Param_Codes_In_HEX: "+Param_Codes_In_HEX);
    int paramCode = Integer.parseInt(Param_Codes_In_HEX, 16);
    if ((0x000000ff & cbuf[3]) ==0) {
    EnumParamCodes enumParamCode = 
         EnumConverterUtil.getEnumFor(EnumParamCodes.class, paramCode);
    System.out.println("Param_code " + paramCode + ": " + enumParamCode);
    }
  else if((0x000000ff & cbuf[3]) ==64)
   {
    paramCode = 0x0000ffff & paramCode ;
    EnumParamCodes enumParamCode = EnumConverterUtil.getEnumFor(EnumParamCodes.class, paramCode);
   System.out.println("Param_code " + paramCode + ": " + enumParamCode);
   }
  else if ((0x000000ff & cbuf[3]) ==128) {
      paramCode = 0x00ffffff & paramCode ;
      EnumAlarm enumParamCodeAlarm = EnumConverterUtil.getEnumFor(EnumAlarm.class, paramCode);
      System.out.println("Param_code " + paramCode + ": " + enumParamCodeAlarm);
    } 
  else{
      System.out.println("Error in the body of message");
        }
      }
```

---

Note:
• For Numerical and Enumerative Parameters (ActualValue), the
Param_code corresponds to the ID in the Parameters section

• For Numerical and Enumerative Parameters (SetValue), the
Param_code corresponds to 0x40000000 + the ID in the Parameters
section

• For Alarm Parameters, the Param_code corresponds to 0x80000000
+ the ID in the Parameters section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String getByteString(byte b) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    String digit=Integer.toHexString(b &0xff);
    buf.append(digit);
    if (digit.length()<2) buf.append('0');
    return buf.toString();
}
```

this should get the 0 padding for you

```
String Param_Codes_In_HEX = getByteString(cbuf[2]) + getByteString(cbuf[1]) + getByteString(cbuf[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply:
I check out the new code as you wrote above. i see  result is different. is my if statement correct acording below conditions?
• Option 1: Sometimes the Param_code corresponds to the ID 
• Option 2: Sometimes the Param_code corresponds to 0x40000000 + the ID 
• Option 3: Sometimes the Param_code corresponds to 0x80000000 + the ID

Comment: yes your if looks good. Although you can simplify it. You can write it as if ((0xff & cbuf[3]) ==0x80) ....

Answer (score 0):

The code is rather complicated for what it is doing IMHO. One of the problems is likely to be String concatenation when you want to be doing bit manipulation. e.g. bytes 1,2,3 will become 123 instead of 010203

Comment: It appears you are only interested in the top bits.